# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MYSQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'p.apaterno' in 'field list'

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, phpmyadmin

Tengo una duda respecto a ese error, por que aunque chequee el código no puedo encontrar a que se está refiriendo si yo lo veo bien escrito y los valores están completos.

Yo pienso que el error puede estar apareciendo según estas partes

```
totalregistros = 0;
    modelo = new DefaultTableModel(null, titulos);

    sSQL = "select p.idpersona,p.nombre,p.apaterno,p.amaterno,p.tipo_documento,p.num_documento,"
            + "p.direccion,p.telefono,p.email,c.codigo_cliente from persona p inner join cliente c "
            + "on p.idpersona=c.idpersona where num_documento like '%"
            + buscar + "%' order by idpersona desc";
```

o tal vez

```
public boolean insertar(vcliente dts) {
    sSQL = "insert into persona (nombre,apaterno,amaterno,tipo_documento,num_documento,direccion,telefono,email)"
            + "values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    sSQL2 = "insert into cliente (idpersona,codigo_cliente)"
            + "values ((select idpersona from persona order by idpersona desc limit 1),?)";
    try {

        PreparedStatement pst = cn.prepareStatement(sSQL);
        PreparedStatement pst2 = cn.prepareStatement(sSQL2);

        pst.setString(1, dts.getNombre());
        pst.setString(2, dts.getApaterno());
        pst.setString(3, dts.getAmaterno());
        pst.setString(4, dts.getTipo_documento());
        pst.setString(5, dts.getNum_documento());
        pst.setString(6, dts.getDireccion());
        pst.setString(7, dts.getTelefono());
        pst.setString(8, dts.getEmail());

        pst2.setString(1, dts.getCodigo_cliente());

        int n = pst.executeUpdate();

        if (n != 0) {
            int n2 = pst2.executeUpdate();

            if (n2 != 0) {
                return true;

            } else {
                return false;
            }

        } else {
            return false;
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, e);
        return false;
    }
}



public boolean editar(vcliente dts) {
    sSQL = "update persona set nombre=?,apaterno=?,amaterno=?,tipo_documento=?,num_documento=?,"
            + " direccion=?,telefono=?,email=? where idpersona=?";

    sSQL2 = "update cliente set codigo_cliente=?"
            + " where idpersona=?";
    try {

        PreparedStatement pst = cn.prepareStatement(sSQL);
        PreparedStatement pst2 = cn.prepareStatement(sSQL2);

        pst.setString(1, dts.getNombre());
        pst.setString(2, dts.getApaterno());
        pst.setString(3, dts.getAmaterno());
        pst.setString(4, dts.getTipo_documento());
        pst.setString(5, dts.getNum_documento());
        pst.setString(6, dts.getDireccion());
        pst.setString(7, dts.getTelefono());
        pst.setString(8, dts.getEmail());
        pst.setInt(9, dts.getIdpersona());

        pst2.setString(1, dts.getCodigo_cliente());
        pst2.setInt(2, dts.getIdpersona());

        int n = pst.executeUpdate();

        if (n != 0) {
            int n2 = pst2.executeUpdate();

            if (n2 != 0) {
                return true;

            } else {
                return false;
            }

        } else {
            return false;
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, e);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Gracias ante todo!

Comment: El mensaje de error es claro, **la tabla `persona` no tiene una columna llamada `apaterno`**, ¿puedes confirmar que la columna se llama así realmente?

Comment: Lo que comenta A.Cedano es importante @YahairaFlores , es en realidad el problema, es importante que comentes a Las preguntas de la comunidad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema que presentas es especificado en el error:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MYSQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown
>   column 'p.apaterno' in 'field list'

Estas haciendo referencia a un campo llamado `paterno` de la tabla  `persona`, pero **este campo no existe en la tabla**.

Comment: **CP 301 Cuando se califique con -1, es bueno para el sitio se indique la razón**, esto para mejorar la pregunta, eliminarla o si existen argumentos platicar sobre el tema.

Answer (score 0):

Te sugiero que veas si el nombre que colocaste en la base de datos es el mismo en el codigo de tu ide, quizas no coinciden y por eso manda el error

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/299297)